# xmpp client library for react native

Tags: react-native, xmpp

I am looking for library for xmpp which support all the features like messaging, presence, audio/video calling etc in react native.
I have tried following libraries:

1. xmpp/client
2. stanza.io
3. stroph

I have tried xmpp/client but it does not support jingle. stanza.io supports jingle and is working in react but in react native jingle is not working. I have not tested stroph because of no proper documentation.

For stanza.io it is working fine in react but when I tested it in react native, I am having issue with webrtc. I am getting following error in both expo or react-native-cli:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.pc.oniceconnectionstatechange=function ()
{
    _this.onIceStateChange();
}')
```

Comment: Hello Is this issue solved?

Comment: @saiteja No, still not solved.

Answer (score 0):

Have not tested its support of jingle yet, but we successfully use xmpp/client in our project https://github.com/dappros/ethora/tree/main/client-reactnative for all messaging + we also do video and voice messages but not direct WebRTC calls. Works in React.js too.

I think Stanza and Strophe are discontinued now so xmpp/client has become de-facto the main option.

Do you still have an issue with jingle or did you implement your webrtc signalling some other way? I'm wondering as we'll be looking at the best approach here as well. In the previous project we have implemented our WebRTC initial handshake ourselves via XMPP and then use WebRTC data channel for the rest of the signalling.